# Laravel including "appends" attribute while creating new resource

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using **appends** attribute of laravel model 'Contact' to return a custom field 'image_url' with json response.

I also made an accessor `getImageUrlAttribute` for it.

All working fine except create method. I am using

```
Contact::create(Input::except('_token');
```

Its raising an exception:

> "Unknown column image_url in field list".

This `image_url` field is what I am using as append and added to `$append` array of Contact model.

```
protected $appends = ['image_url'];
```

So its adding this custom attribute while creating a new resource. I googled a lot about this but all I got is how to use it to append extra attributes while fetching data. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory - you don't have `image_url` column in the table. It has nothing to do with `appends`, but rather that you have it in your input.

Comment: I checked it carefully many times but there is no key image_url in that array I m using in Contact::create() . Its including that key automatically @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_

Comment: It deosn't include antything automagically. Replace `Input::except` with `Input::only`, where you specify, which fields you need.